# What is the fastest way to save a large pandas DataFrame to S3?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, amazon-s3

I am trying to figure out what is the fastest way to write a LARGE pandas DataFrame to S3 filesystem. I am currently trying two ways:

1) Through gzip compression (BytesIO) and boto3

```py
gz_buffer = BytesIO()

with gzip.GzipFile(mode='w', fileobj=gz_buffer) as gz_file:
    df.to_csv(TextIOWrapper(gz_file, 'utf8'), index=False)

s3_resource = boto3.resource('s3')
s3_object = s3_resource.Object(bucket, s3_path + name_zip)
s3_object.put(Body=gz_buffer.getvalue())
```

which for a dataframe of 7M rows takes around 420seconds to write to S3.

2) Through writing to csv file without compression (StringIO buffer)

```py
csv_buffer = StringIO()
data.to_csv(csv_buffer)
s3_resource = boto3.resource('s3')
s3_resource.Object(bucket, s3_path + name_csv).put(Body=csv_buffer.getvalue())
```

which takes around 371 seconds...

The question is:
Is there any other faster way to write a pandas dataframe to S3?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use multi-part uploads to make the transfer to S3 faster. Compression makes the file smaller, so that will help too.

```
import boto3
s3 = boto3.client('s3')

csv_buffer = BytesIO()
df.to_csv(csv_buffer, compression='gzip')

# multipart upload
# use boto3.s3.transfer.TransferConfig if you need to tune part size or other settings
s3.upload_fileobj(csv_buffer, bucket, key)
```

The docs for `s3.upload_fileobj` are here: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.upload_fileobj

Comment: Your code gives me "TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str' ". Any suggestions appreciated.

Comment: For `TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str' `, `StringIO` instead of `BytesIO` works for me

Comment: With StringIO, I get ``TypeError: Unicode-objects must be encoded before hashing``

Comment: [This SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66902759/863923) answer fixed the hashing error for me

Comment: i tried this, but nothing gets uploaded. There are no error or anything either

Comment: @Raksha you need to `csv_buffer.seek(0)` to rewind the buffer.

Answer (score 3):

You can try using `s3fs` with `pandas` compression to upload to S3. `StringIO` or `BytesIO` are memory hogging.

```py
import s3fs
import pandas as pd

s3 = s3fs.S3FileSystem(anon=False)
df = pd.read_csv("some_large_file")
with s3.open('s3://bucket/file.csv.gzip','w') as f:
    df.to_csv(f, compression='gzip')
```

Comment: I am getting errors with this: 
`botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the ListObjectsV2 operation: Access Denied` .... I have opened up access on my bucket though. I have made read public and I have added the following under bucket policy under my account #  `[                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:PutObjectAcl",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:GetObjectAcl",
                "s3:DeleteObject"] `

Comment: Get warning: compression has no effect when passing file-like object as input

Answer (score 2):

It really depends on the content, but that is not related to `boto3`. Try first to dump your `DataFrame` locally and see what's fastest and what size you get.

Here are some suggestions that we have found to be fast, for cases between a few MB to over 2GB (although, for more than 2GB, you really want parquet and possibly split it into a parquet dataset):

1. Lots of mixed text/numerical data (SQL-oriented content): use `df.to_parquet(file)`.
2. Mostly numerical data (e.g. if your columns `df.dtypes` indicate a happy `numpy` array of a single type, not `Object`): you can try `df_to_hdf(file, 'key')`.

One bit of advice: try to split your `df` in some shards that are meaningful to you (e.g., by time for timeseries). Especially if you have a lot of updates to a single shard (e.g. the last one in a time series), it will make your download/upload much faster.

What we have found is that, HDF5 are bulkier (uncompressed), but they save/load fantastically fast from/into memory.  Parquets are by default snappy-compressed, so they tend to be smaller (depending on the entropy of your data, of course; penalty for you if you save totally random numbers).

For `boto3` client, both `multipart_chunksize` and `multipart_threshold` are 8MB by default, which is often a fine choice. You can check via:

```
tc = boto3.s3.transfer.TransferConfig()
print(f'chunksize: {tc.multipart_chunksize}, threshold: {tc.multipart_threshold}')
```

Also, the default is to use 10 threads for each upload (which does nothing unless the size of your object is larger than the threshold above).

Another question is how to upload many files efficiently. That is **not** handled by any definition in `TransferConfig`. But I digress, the original question is about a single object.

Answer (score 0):

First, check that you are writing to a bucket that is in the **same region** as your notebook.

Second, you can try the option to upload using **multi-part** which takes files that are larger than a few GB and upload them in parallel:

```
from boto3.s3.transfer import TransferConfig

def s3_upload_file(args):     
    s3 = boto3.resource('s3')

    GB = 1024 ** 3
    config = TransferConfig(multipart_threshold=5 * GB)

    s3.meta.client.upload_file(args.path, args.bucket, os.path.basename(args.path),Config=config)
```

Comment: multi-part via upload_file is good advice, but you are setting the threshold to 5GB, so there will be no benefit for files smaller than 5GB. better to use the default value.