# Saving file like object to s3 i get error: Unicode-objects must be encoded before hashing

Tags: python, amazon-s3

Here is my code.

```
import boto3
import pandas as pd
import requests
from io import StringIO

campaign_buffer=StringIO()

r = requests.get('https://.... output=csv....')

if r.status_code==200:
    r.encoding='utf-8'
    request_txt = r.text
    campaigns = StringIO(request_txt)
    campaigns_pd = pd.read_csv(campaigns, sep=",")
    campaigns_pd.columns=campaigns_pd.columns.str.replace(':','_')
    campaigns_pd.drop('images_thumb', inplace=True, axis=1)
    campaigns_pd.to_csv(campaign_buffer)
else:
    print('error')

bucket = 'name'
key = 'folder/test.csv'

client = boto3.client('s3')
client.upload_fileobj(campaign_buffer, bucket, key)
```

Last line of code caused error:
TypeError: Unicode-objects must be encoded before hashing

Any ideas how to solve the problem?

Comment: Well, what exactly did you not understand about the error message?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're writing to a `StringIO()`, which has no intrinsic encoding, and you can't write something that can't be encoded into bytes into S3. To do this without having to re-encode whatever you've written to `campaing_buffer`:

1. Make your `campaign_buffer` a `BytesIO()` instead of a `StringIO()`
2. Add `mode="wb"` and `encoding="UTF-8"` to the `to_csv` call
3. Do `campaign_buffer.seek(0)` to rewind the in-memory file before uploading

Comment: Thank you for your recommendation. Now I get error: TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str' in line: campaigns_pd.to_csv(campaign_buffer,mode="wb",encoding="UTF-8")

Comment: @Rafalik Did you make `campaign_buffer` a `BytesIO()`? You can also try with `mode="w"`...

Comment: Yes, I set campaign_buffer=io.BytesIO()
Currently, I've changed to_csv > to_parquet with engine='pyarrow' and it works for me.
I will also check your  last suggestion with "w". Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into a similar issue and would like to update the answer provided by @AKX. A couple of key pieces of context.

- You will need to use a pandas version that [includes the fix](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/pull/35129) "support binary file handles in to_csv". The example below was tested on Pandas 1.3.2, Python 3.8, and boto3 1.17.106.
- The answer by @AKX and the following example use the high level `s3.resource()` API. I will also include an example for using the `s3.client()` API but keep in mind, they provide different methods for performing similar tasks.

Here is an example using `boto3.resource("s3")`

```
from io import BytesIO
import boto3
import pandas
from pandas import util
df = util.testing.makeMixedDataFrame()
s3_resource = boto3.resource("s3")
campaign_buffer = BytesIO()
df.to_csv(campaign_buffer, sep=",", index=False, mode="wb", encoding="UTF-8")
df.seek(0)  # Make sure the stream position is at the beginning!
s3_resource.Object("test-bucket", "test_df_from_resource.csv").put(Body=campaign_buffer.getvalue())
```

You should then receive a confirmation message that looks similar to the following:

```
>> {'ResponseMetadata': {'RequestId': 'request-id-value',
'HostId': '###########',
  'HTTPStatusCode': 200,
  'HTTPHeaders': {'x-amz-id-2': '############',
   'x-amz-request-id': '00000',
   'date': 'Tue, 31 Aug 2021 00:00:00 GMT',
   'x-amz-server-side-encryption': 'value',
   'etag': '"xxxx"',
   'server': 'AmazonS3',
   'content-length': '0'},
  'RetryAttempts': 0},
 'ETag': '"xxxx"',
 'ServerSideEncryption': 'value'}
```

And here is an example using `boto3.client("s3")`

```
from io import BytesIO
import boto3
import pandas
from pandas import util
df = util.testing.makeMixedDataFrame()
s3_client = boto3.client("s3")
campaign_buffer = BytesIO()
df.to_csv(campaign_buffer, sep=",", index=False, mode="wb", encoding="UTF-8")
df.seek(0)
s3_client.upload_fileobj(campaign_buffer, Bucket="test-bucket", Key="test_df_from_client.csv")
```

Hope seeing both examples helps anyone looking for an easy way to upload a Pandas dataframe to S3.